# How to print output of a stream in bash?

Tags: bash

I have an output stream:

```
xxx 2>&1 | grep 'Word:' | sed -e ...
```

The output of a certain command contains `Word:`. I can `grep` this word and do the rest of my commands. It works well. At the end I have the output I was expecting. But now I want that the full log (so everything in the stream `2>&1`) is shown in the logs on my screen, before grepping the `Word:` and doing my stuff.

If I do `xxx 2>&1`, then I can see the full output I want to have on my screen, but because I have to `grep` on it, it isn't shown anymore in my command `xxx 2>&1 | grep 'Word:' | sed -e ...`

I was thinking about something like:

```
2>&1 | echo 2>&1 | grep 'Word:' | sed -e ...
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tee`: Copy stdin to stdout, as well as files specified in command-line arguments.

You can copy the stdin to stderr with `tee`:

```
xxx 2>&1 | tee /dev/stderr | grep ...
```

In case `/dev/stderr` isn't available, use `/proc/self/fd/2`.

Comment: Note that `/proc/` works differently in different operating systems, if it's mounted at all. It's not part of bash.

Comment: @ghoti One can also argue that `/dev/stdin | stdout | stderr` isn't part of Bash, too.

Comment: Actually, those *are* part of bash. Check the bottom of the "REDIRECTION" section of the man page. "*If the operating system on which bash is running provides these special files, bash will use them; otherwise it will emulate them internally with the behavior described below.*"

Comment: @ghoti But wait, does it still work the same when supplied as cmdline arguments? I mean, does bash handle cmdline args "internally"?